# Medieval infantry deployed in ranks of #(?) men (formation depth)?

Tags: middle-ages, warfare, tactics

We know quite a lot about Greek phalanx, its deployment and depth and, I believe, about Roman legions as well.

But do we know anything about Western European infantry formations of high/late middle ages? How wide and deep were its infantry ranks? Are there any contemporary accounts or at least rough estimates that could shed some light on this matter?

Comment: This is from a period that comes a bit later, but in spirit the organization was similar (replace the firearms with bowmen, and drop the dragoons): http://www.revolutionspodcast.com/2013/10/supplemental-the-armies.html